# Passing web socket requests from Nginx to uWSGI server

Tags: nginx, websocket, uwsgi

I have Nginx running on server `a` (port 8000) and `uWSGI` running on server `b` (port 8001). `b` already serves a web socket at `ws://b:8001/s`. I would like to configure `a` as a reverse proxy also giving access to this web socket at `ws://a:8000/s`.

I am interested (if I understand correctly and this is the right approach) in `a` relaying the original HTTP request to `b` and in `b` initiating the protocol upgrade (as would also happen in the absence of a proxy), not in `a` initiating the protocol upgrade, as seems to happen in [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) example.

What Nginx `location` block would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That proved straigthforward enough. The following `location` block apparently does the trick (for Nginx 1.10.3 and uWSGI 2.0.17.1):

```
location /s {
  proxy_pass http://b:8001/s;
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
}
```